# Check if string is GUID in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on ASP.NET Web Forms application. I have class `Client` with property

`public string Id { get; set; }`

In several places I need to check if the `Id` is in fact a guid. For example I have this code :

```
Guid GuidID;
foreach (Client item in clients)
{
    bool isGUID = Guid.TryParse(item.Id, out GuidID);
    if (!isGUID)
    {
        hasExistingClient = true;
    }
}
if (hasExistingClient)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

which is a lot of code just to check if in a `List<Client> clients` (of clients) I have a `Client` with a real `Id` and not a guid. I would like, if possible to make Linq query out of this. Something like

```
if (clients.Any(c => c.Id is GUID))
```

but I don't know what to write on the place of `is GUID`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Guid guidID;
bool hasGUID = clients.Any(c => Guid.TryParse(c.Id, out guidID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract values from item of type Guid by using OfType. However, I suspect you would need this as you have values in string.

var result = items.OfType();

So in that you case you can use this:

```
   var items = new[] {"{Guid 1}", "{Guid 2}"}.ToList();
            var guidItem = new Guid();
            var result = from item in items
                where Guid.TryParse(item, out guidItem)
                select guidItem;

            if (result.Any())
            {
                // you have got some itesm... 
            }
```